# Jack fails on Preview 4 with com/android/jack/api/v03/Api03Config error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jack-and-jill

I have an issue with the latest Android Studio (Preview 4) and compiling with Jack.

I get this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com/android/jack/api/v03/Api03Config
```

Any ideas ?

My gradle file : http://pastie.org/private/ieb3wbkxhr1zbk0xr5dssw

Stacktrace from Gradle : http://pastie.org/private/agjsdikwk23zmaz2qz6xw

Computer is running WIN10 up-to-date and this bug is not related to my antivirus as it could be mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211732 (I don't have nay anyway :) )

> Posted as a bug in Android Bug Tracker :
>
> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214156
>
> Please star :)

Comment: Star please https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214156

Comment: Don't have an answer, but this is working for me with plugins version 2.2.0-alpha2 and 2.2.0-alpha3.  Not with 2.2.0-alpha4

Comment: I'm also using 2.2 Preview 4 with the same target and build tools as you. I get this exception only if I run installDebug. When I use stacktrace this error is spit out

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.jack.api.v03.Api03Config

Comment: I noticed that `:app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug` fails only if I run it from console. If you run it or some other task that depends on it like `assembleDebug` from `Gradle projects` tool window then it succeeds.

Comment: @mixel I posted that myself, and any of the solution solved my problem.

@ All : Even assembleDebug fails for me :(

Comment: Change gradle plugin version to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3' solved this,but do not know why alpha4 failed.

Comment: Yes, I know that rolling back to previous alpha works :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'`